# How to assign different authorizations to different AWS Cognito groups for a static site served by AWS Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We have implemented the following AWS solution in order to publish a static html site on the internet :

https://github.com/aws-samples/cloudfront-authorization-at-edge

How can we manage to assign different authorization to different groups of the Cognito user pool?

For example:

- users in group A should see the whole site
- users in group B should
  see the whole site except the contents of folder "private"
- users in
  group C should see only the root index.html

I know that I can create different IAM role with sperific IAM policies to attach to the cognito groups in the user pool, but I don't know what to specify in the rule, because the site is served by Cloudfront, not from the S3 bucket.